# Import Django class from view to another file

Tags: python, django, django-views

Good afternoon everybody,

I'm fighting with my custom class defined in my Django view in order to use it inside another python file which let me to manage my Menu.

This class is pretty simple, but she uses a custom middleware too:

```
# main.views.py file
class MyClass:
    def my_main_function(self, request):
        my_queryset = myModel.objects.filter(application=request.cur_app, display=True).order_by('order')
        return my_queryset

    def toto(self):
        list_test = self.my_main_function()
        return list_test
```

`request.cur_app` corresponds to my middleware defined in middleware.py file.

I created `toto()` because I would like to use `my_main_function` inside another file called `menus.py` which doesn't handle `request`.

In this file, I have:

```
from .views.main import MyClass

for element in MyClass.toto():
    ... do something ...
```

But this is the issue encountered:

> toto() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

I'm conscient there is a possibility of huge issues in my code, because I'm learning programmation at the same time. Be indulgent.

Comment: `MyClass().toto()` or make it classmethod

Comment: @BearBrown By updating `MyClass().toto()`, I get `my_main_function() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'`

Comment: yes because you call it `self.my_main_function()`  without the `request`

Comment: `self.my_main_function(self.request)` gives me: `MyClass object has no attribute request` Hum

Comment: and yes again, where do you see the attribute `request` of the class?

Comment: probable you don't understand what you really want and me too.

Comment: Invert your intention: extract `my_main_function` internals into common method end utilize it in the view and the _another module_. Before doing that you have to understand how this `application=request.cur_app` is supposed to work when current scope does not have any "request"s.

Comment: @IvanStarostin I will search on this way. But actually I don't know How I can handle request's if the scope doesn't have any request as a global way.